# request.context won't close connection

Tags: go, http.client

I'm using context.Context to cancel a http request

I find although I got the "context cancel", the underlying socket connection is still available, and I can get the response after a few seconds. Is it designed this way to read response once request is set out?

This is the code

```
func SendRequest(ctx context.Context, url string) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    req = req.WithContext(ctx)

    res, err := client.Do(req)
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Printf("%s Canceled\n", url)
        //client.Transport.(*http.Transport).CancelRequest(req)
        //client.Transport.(*http.Transport).CloseIdleConnections()
    }
    if res != nil {
        defer res.Body.Close()
    }
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed: %v\n", err)
    } else {
        io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, res.Body)
        fmt.Printf("return status: %d\n", url, res.StatusCode)
    }
}
```

The URL I'm requesting will return after several seconds, so I can still read the response body, and the connection was closed after the process exits.

Here is a simple code to reproduce the issue

```
func client() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    client := http.DefaultClient
    request, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:9090", nil)
    req := request.WithContext(ctx)

    go func() {
        client.Do(req)
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Duration(1) * time.Second)
    cancel()

    <-time.After(time.Duration(10) * time.Second)

}

func sayhelloName(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(10) * time.Second)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello world!")
}

func server() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", sayhelloName)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

connection was closed after exactly 10 second
[image: connection was closed after exactly 10 second]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to do anything yourself to cancel a request when the context is cancelled. This is already handled by the standard http package [as documented](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Context).

All you should need is:

```
func SendRequest(ctx context.Context, url string) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    req = req.WithContext(ctx)

    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, res.Body)
    fmt.Printf("return status: %d\n", url, res.StatusCode)
}
```

### EDIT

Your TCP dump confirms that everything is working as it should, and precisely as I have described above.

To break it down:

Your outbound request is indeed being cancelled after one second, as your TCP dump confirms:

```
6 2017-12-04 06:10:21.864955 0.0993000      40 TCP       17503 → 9090 [FIN, ACK] Seq=96 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0
7 2017-12-04 06:10:21.864955 0.0000000      40 TCP       9090 → 17503 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=97 Win-7936 Len=0
```

That `FIN` on line 6 means the HTTP client is telling the server "I'm done talking to you".  The `ACK` on line 7 means the server responded to the request, and closed the connection.

However, your HTTP handler ignores the cancelled request,and attempts to respond anyway, generating line 8:

```
8 2017-12-04 06:10:30.868955 9.004000     169 HTTP      HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (text/plain)
```

But then the server receives the message that the connection is invalid:

```
9 2017-12-04 06:10:30.868955  0.000000      40 TCP       17503 → 8080 [RST, ACK] Seq=97 Ack=130 Win=0 Len=0
```

The `RST` means the connection has been reset, and is currently invalid. This is because the connection was terminated 9 seconds earlier.

So you see, your request is cancelled immediately, exactly as it should.

The only improvement you could add to your code is to have your HTTP handler in the server actually detect and honor such cancellations, by exiting early when the incoming request has been cancelled.

Comment: what i want to do is to close the connection once the context is canceled. Transport.CancelRequest can help to close the connection as the document says, but it doesn't look like so, and it's deprecated. So if Request.WithContext can't help to close the connection, how can i do that? Thanks!

Comment: @isaac: As I said in my answer: this is already handled by the standard http package. When the context is cancelled, the connection will be closed. Further, [as documented](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport.CancelRequest), `CancelRequest` is deprecated. Don't use that any more.

Comment: OK, @Flimzy, thanks for the reply. I understand what you trying to say. But what i wanted to know is whether it's possible to close connection immediately when i cancel it? apparently Request.WithContext can't achieve this. I can get the response after I cancel it and only then the connection will close. Force to close the connection is my intention.

Comment: @isaac: What evidence do you have that the connection doesn't close immediately?

Comment: @isaac: Your additional information confirms what I've been saying all along. I've updated my answer with a detailed explanation.

Comment: looks like i misunderstand the meaning of FIN and RST flag, you're right, the connection was closed once I cancel the context. Thanks for the reply.